# WebCrypto Import ECDH JWK, Key Usage Error

Tags: javascript, webcrypto

So I'm currently trying to export a ECDH private key into an Uint8Array and import it afterward. Here is my code, I'm using Google Chrome 117 on Ubuntu, unfortunately the following error keeps coming :(

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.

```
    str2ab(str: string) {
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
        const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
          bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buf;
    }

    ab2str(buf: any) {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
    }

    let keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-384",
        },
        true,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"],
    );

    const exported = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("jwk", keyPair.privateKey);
    const exportedKeyBuffer = str2ab(JSON.stringify(exported)));

    const privKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "jwk",
      JSON.parse(ab2str(exportedKeyBuffer)),
      {
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-384",
      },
      false,
      ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"]
    );
```

Comment: Note that `keyBuffer` is not defined in your code ( maybe you mean `exportedKeyBuffer`). Also, the definitions of `str2ab()` and `ab2str()` are missing. Post a complete executable code. I cannot reproduce the issue with my own implementations.

Comment: @Topaco Hey sry for posting this incomplete code, I added the helper functions and changed the variables

Comment: Apart from a typo with a bracket, the code seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/5swczyux/1/. Maybe a problem with your browser or your particular browser version. Check if it works in another browser.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you so much for the fast response, I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu, added this to the description. Yeah maybe there's a problem :(

Comment: So I guess, we can close this question, because I figured there's a problem with storing and retrieving the array Buffer in the webauthn large blob extension.